# Binding Angular Object to Polymer 1.0

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding, polymer-1.0

I have an custom element:

```
<my-element options='{{myOptions}}'></my-element>
```

Like this, the `ready` callback in the web component just receives `{{myOptions}}` for the `options` property. I've tried some tools, none worked.

I then read [here](https://pascalprecht.github.io/2014/10/25/integrating-web-components-with-angularjs/) that you can do a callback that will trigger once the property was changed (attributeChangedCallback), so I did some hack that postpones the `ready` callback until a boolean flag is set to true on that callback, but that's an ugly fix.

Also - it only works with Chrome.

Can someone share what's the best cross-browser solution to make the Angular bind to Polymer ?

Comment: I think you may need to add polyfills for make it working..just a guess.. as shadow DOM is not supported by all broswer

Comment: That's not the issue, unfortunately. The web components work, I'm aware of the polyfills needed. The thing is that the element is registered and created before the angular interpolation. Not sure how to catch the after the interpolation.

Comment: Is this `<my-element options='{{myOptions}}'></my-element>` in the template of a Polymer element or in the template of an Angular component?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer This is in my Angular view, making use of the component. `myOptions` is an angular object.

Comment: What exactly is not working. Does the Polymer element not receive the `myOptions` value or do you expect Angular to get noticed about changes by `<my-element>` on the `options` property or the `myOptions` value?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The first. Polymer receives inside options property just a string: "{{myOptions}}". And on the `ready` event in the Polymer element I need to fire some ajaxs depending on its data. (I don't care about two way binding, my angular doesn't need to know about updates, I just want to pass the data to the element)

Answer (score 1):

`<my-element options='{{myOptions}}'></my-element>` binds `myOptions` stringyfied, for object binding use

```
<my-element [options]='myOptions'></my-element>
```

To make Polymer awar of later changes to a property of `myOptions` you can delay the assignment of the value to `myOptions` until it is fully built on the Angular side. If you pass an object and change a property of that object, Angular doesn't recognize it.

You could also explicitly notify the Polymer element about the change using Polymers API

```
@Component({
  selector: 'angular-comp',
  template: `
<my-element #options options='{{myOptions}}'></my-element>
`
export class AngularComponent {
  @ViewChild('options') options;

  constructor() {
    this.options = {};
  }
  myOptions:any;
  // or some event handler or similar that isn't called before ngAfterViewInit (for example click, ...)
  ngAfterViewInit() { 
    this.options.someProp = "someValue";
    options.set('options.someProp', this.options.someProp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the first half of my problem! It now receives an object instead of the string, but it happens before Angular populates data into the object. How does the polymer know when the data has changed?

Comment: I tried placing it in `ng-if` or `ng-show` but that messes up with the DOM in a way that it recreates the element.

Comment: Is that in Angular 2.0? I'm using Angular 1.3 (sorry I didn't mention). But doesn't the change need to be in the Polymer element? How does that integrate with the Polymer component? I thought there should be some event in the Polymer component that should be triggered, in their documentation it states that declared element properties are notified of updates: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html

Comment: Yup, Angular2. Sorry I missed that. The part with `options.set(...)` should apply anyway.

Comment: I tried in my controller: `document.querySelector('#myElementId').set('options', $scope.myOptions);` but nothing triggers in the element. In which event should it change? I guess I have to do it in some other event.. ready won't do it since it won't have the data by then.

Comment: As far as I understand you question you don't want to notify Polymer about `options` to be changed but about a property of `options` which would be `....set('options.someProp', $scope.myOptions.someProp)`

Comment: Update(!!): I've managed to do this using an observer on the options property.

Comment: It's about the entire object, not just a property. I'm getting that object dynamically and want to pass it down.

Comment: I guess this needs a Plunker to reproduce.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer wasn't that question related to Angular1? but you have added Angular2 solution..

Comment: @PankajParkar You are right. I didn't recognize because I have my filter set up to only see Angular2 questions but it got in my list because it has the Polymer tag which I also monitor.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer np..I just asked.. because OP also had added comment..that my 1st half problem has solved.. so I was in a question, I'm missing something to read :D